# Ativar e desativar Children gameobject c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Bom fiz um script onde onde ativa e desativa em num os `gameobject`, queria saber como faço pra ativar e desativar os filhos também dentro desse script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class OBJETOS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] arrayObjetos;

    public void botoes(int num)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayObjetos.Length; i++)
{
    if( arrayObjetos[num] == arrayObjetos[i])
{
    arrayObjetos[i].SetActive(true);
    }else{
    arrayObjetos[i].SetActive(false);
}
}
}
}
//sei que pode ser assim GameObject meuobjeto = GameObject.Find("meuobjeto");
// e assim tbm GameObject ChildGameObjeto1 = ParentGameObject.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isto desativa todos filhos do gameObject que você botar o script:

```
    foreach (Transform t in transform)
    {
          t.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

Comment: sim, mais no script onde eu fiz acima, onde eu coloco ele?

Comment: abaixos dos?     arrayObjetos[i].SetActive(true);
    }else{
    arrayObjetos[i].SetActive(false);

Comment: eu não in tendi muito bem sua pergunta. Pelo que entendi, você precisa desativar todos fillhos do objeto que você colocar o script. Se for isso, você pode botar no `void start()` que quando o jogo começar, este objeto será desativado.Mas se não é isso, por favor, explique melhor sua pergunta

Comment: Ah ta, você quer que desative os filhos do objeto que será desativado?

Comment: conseguir adicionei o forech e gg vlw